# Does React 18 batch render after state updates inside lifecycle methods

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state-management, react-18

Since React 18 introduced batch rendering in all places, we've been facing issues in our application. In our application, re-render needs to happen right away rather than batching. So we used flushSync() for every setState() call. Now we face an error/warning in the console "flushSync was called from inside a lifecycle method. React cannot flush them when React is already rendering. Consider moving this call to a scheduler task of the microtask". Is there any way we can use multiple setStates inside a handler and not have them batched?

Comment: You can try using `queueMicrotask(() => flushSync(() => setState()))`, but I think that there is some design flaw if you need to use `flushSync` so many times.

Comment: Maybe, or may not be. The thing is, we have a lot of handler functions that does multiple state updates. Where each of them triggers a re-render to a specific part of the UI flow. Now that React batches all the state update calls inside a single handler, we're not able to update the UI as required like before.